# How do you UV unwrap or assign materials without applying formative modifiers?

Tags: modeling, uv, modifiers

I'm trying to model a laptop with mostly modifiers and non-destructive modeling, but now that I'm satisfied with the shapes I would like to start working on the textures, but if possible I would like to avoid applying them, in case I need to make changes later. 
[image]

Is there a way to assign different materials to constructed faces, or to even UV unwrap to use textures, while keeping the modifiers?

Comment: What about making a copy of the mesh and apply the modifiers on that? You would then need to redo the UV unwrapping if you go back. But then you could do a Data Transfer from the old to the new.

Comment: Why do you consider assigning materials to faces or UV coordinates to vertices destructive?

Comment: It's not the act of assigning materials in itself, it's the act of applying the modifiers, but in order to target faces for materials, created with booleans, for instance,one would have to apply it first. I'm looking for a workaround.